# When is the L2-norm likelihood function appropriate in Bayesian MCMC inference?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood

The following likelihood function can be found in [reservoir simulation literature](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~hou/papers/MCMC_SISC.pdf):

$$P(F|k) \propto \exp\left(-\frac{||F-F_k||^2}{\sigma_f^2}\right)$$

Where:

$k$  = model

$F$ = data

$F_k$ = simulation of data

$\sigma_f$ = precision of data $F$

I am used to likelihood functions that are equal to the pdf of the model (e.g. likelihood function for coin flips is given by the binomial pdf).

Can you offer any context or explanation of this type of likelihood function? I believe it has something to do with the assumption that the model misfit $|F - F_k|$ is normally distributed but I need more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is proportional to that exponential function is because it contains an intractable normalizing constant, similar to that you find in the Ising Model or the Bingham distribution, which is not available in closed-form and depends on the parameters of interest. More specifically, the likelihood is not complete. The complete likelihood is of the form:

$$P(F|k) = \frac{1}{Z(...)}\exp\left(-\frac{||F-F_k||^2}{\sigma_f^2}\right),$$
where $Z(...)$ cannot be obtained in closed form and then you need numerical methods.

See also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham_distribution

https://dslpitt.org/uai/papers/06/p359-murray.pdf

`http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947316302687`